# Angular HighCharts Show All Elements even there are big differance between amounts

Tags: angular, highcharts

Hello I have an angular application and I use highcharts for graphs. Everything is working well but I have problem with values. Because some values is about millions another is just thousands. So in graph I can't see that small value. I use stacked bar. I created working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kapb1c)

this is my chartoption

```
this.chartOptions = {
        chart: {  backgroundColor: null,  plotShadow: false, plotBorderWidth: null, plotBackgroundColor: null },
        xAxis: { categories:categories},  stackLabels: { enabled: false},
        title: { text: '' }, credits: { enabled: false }, legend: { enabled: true }, tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
      },
        plotOptions: {minPointLength: 10, column: { stacking: 'normal', dataLabels: {enabled: false } } }, series:el
      };
```

How can I see all elements in graph even there are big differance between amounts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of debugging details do you need ?. Problem is clear . There is also example code and demo for this. So tell me what is missing then I will complete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option which came to my mind is using the `breaks` feature on the yAxis to change the yAxis readability.

The basic demo which should explain to you what I have in mind: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v02Ls1ej/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.breaks